# i want to make four letter one word game. i have designed xml but getting problem in main activity java.

Tags: android

i want to make four letter one word game. I have designed xml using four imagebutton and randomly load from string array, but how to code entire java file. i am beginner to programming.

Comment: Then start by learning how to code on Java first.

Answer (score 1):

Look at some free android Java tutorials on youtube or read some from places like code+tuts or mybringback. Nobody is going to hand you code.

Guru Raj is right, use lists because they are less of a pain to use and also fetch your words from an external csv file or so.

That way you can pull your word library from wikipedia. Then you can pull random words from the file, add them to a list and work with that list.

This is a link to my mediafire source as well as an app called Game of Words. Maybe it's something along the lines of what you need. Use it for whatever you want, you can even sell the app that you come up with. Try and PM me to show me your work if you do.

APK file - http://www.mediafire.com/download/bhol315o30t603j/GameOfWords.apk

and this is the eclipse source

http://www.mediafire.com/download/im47iwjb14ebniq/Game_of_Words_%284%29.7z

Answer (score -2):

> use lists instead of array you may use mapping also